# CodeDeploy Error: "The revision size is too large. Its maximum size is 51200B."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to set up a deployment process as follows: Travis-CI.com grabs the codebase (NodeJS), builds and tests it, uploads it to S3 as a zip and then kicks off a CodeDeploy deployment (ECS). Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '12'

before_deploy:
  - zip -rq latest *
  - mkdir -p upload
  - mv latest.zip upload/latest.zip

deploy:
- provider: s3
  bucket: "myBucket"
  access_key_id:
    secure: keystuff
  secret_access_key:
    secure: keystuff
  local_dir: upload
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: develop
- provider: codedeploy
  bucket: "myBucket"
  key: latest.zip
  bundle_type: zip
  application: "myApp"
  deployment_group: "myDeploymentGroup"
  region: "us-east-1"
  access_key_id:
    secure: keystuff
  secret_access_key:
    secure: keystuff
  on:
    branch: develop
```

My appspec.yml (Truth be told I'm not sure what should go in here.):

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
```

The upload to S3 succeeds, but the deployment task fails with the following error:

`The revision size is too large. Its maximum size is 51200B.`

I see this error under CodeDeploy > Deployments > DeploymentID.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here - any insight?

Comment: Super strange, I could deploy a 1.2 GB file with CodeDeploy.

Comment: I have the same problem. This is utterly none-sense from AWS. All limits are at least 512 MB. Not sure where they got the 51 KB from

Comment: @opticon - did you find a solution this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue was because our zipped code in S3 passed the 51kb limit. My zipped code is 62kb. I deleted some files, tested it again, and it worked.

Comment: So what, AWS CodeDeploy only lets you deploy apps with max 51kb of source code? It sounds ridiculous , I got same error, but I am using CodeCommit and CodeBuild.