# How do you reference dockerhub as a source for your application image within the codedeploy appspec?

Tags: aws-code-deploy, dockerhub, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I already implemented dockerhub to source the baseline image in the buildspec to package the application, then tag/push back to DockerHub:

```
- docker tag XXXX/docker_demo:demo XXXX/docker_demo:demo
- docker push XXXX/docker_demo:demo
```

This works... However, when running a CodeDeploy Application (tied via a CodePipeline) it complains: 
[image]

Please note that I have already viewed: 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=785905
And
[CodeDeploy Error: "The revision size is too large. Its maximum size is 51200B."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062615/codedeploy-error-the-revision-size-is-too-large-its-maximum-size-is-51200b)
Neither really answer the original question posted (over a year ago; so hoping there have been some developments since).

If I didn't know better, I would guess that I might be forced to use ECR?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicated CodeDeploy is expecting an appspec file (hence the small filesize) and you have provided a zip artifact file.

We need more information on the Deployment action in CodePipeline. Are you using Amazon ECS or Amazon ECS (Blue/Green) deploy action? Remember you will not use "CodeDeploy" action in CodePipeline to deploy to ECS. That action is for EC2 deployments with CodeDeploy.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually solved this via CodePipeline. But there is certainly something to be said about AWS exception handling!